# Cannot launch app in Ubuntu Device

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I have just installed the Ubuntu SDK on an Ubuntu 14.10 system (a virtual 32-bit install).  I have also installed Ubuntu Touch on a 2013 Nexus 7.  The device is seen by the host and the device is properly configured in the SDK.  I can open an SSH session from the Device's control list in the SDK.  The device status is "ready" ("has connection" and "has developer mode enabled")

I tried a simple example app (CurrencyConverter) which I can compile and run on the host, and whose click package is validated withput errors or warnings.

The problem is that I cannot download (Publish-> Install on device) the app to the Nexus 7: it always fails.  The output is:

Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:10000' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

Sdk-Launcher> Executing:     /tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.swdev.currencyconverter_0.1_all.click

Sdk-Launcher> Force Install: True

Sdk-Launcher> Skip Uninstall:True

Sdk-Launcher> Launcher PID: 1642

Sdk-Launcher> Installing application .....

Sdk-Launcher> Installing the application failed

From the General Messages tab:

[11:25:41] Lets clear the device tmp folder at phablet@127.0.0.1:10000/home/phablet/dev_tmp

[11:25:41] Lets create the device tmp folder to phablet@127.0.0.1:10000/home/phablet/dev_tmp

[11:25:42] Transfer the click package /usr/bin//home/swdev/SW/build-CurrencyConverter-Ubuntu_Device_GCC_armhf_ubuntu_sdk_14_10_utopic-default/./com.ubuntu.developer.swdev.currencyconverter_0.1_all.click to the device

[11:25:42] ..transfer complete!
List all available click packages on the device

[11:25:43] com.ubuntu.developer.swdev.currencyconverter_0.1_all.click

[11:25:43] Installing com.ubuntu.developer.swdev.currencyconverter_0.1_all.click to device..

[11:25:43] Transaction: Installing files

[11:25:43] Status: 
[11:25:43]  Waiting in queue

[11:25:43] Status:  Starting

[11:25:43] Status:  Finished

[11:25:43] Transaction: Installing files

[11:25:43] Status:  Waiting in queue

[11:25:43] Status:  Waiting for authentication

[11:25:44] Status:  Waiting in queue

[11:25:44] Status:  Starting

[11:25:44] Status:  Finished

[11:25:44] Results:
Fatal error: /home/phablet/dev_tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.swdev.currencyconverter_0.1_all.click failed to install.
WARNING:root:Signature check failed, but installing anyway as requested
Cannot install /home/phablet/dev_tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.swdev.currencyconverter_0.1_all.click: Framework "ubuntu-sdk-14.10" not present on system (use --force-missing-framework option to override)

[11:25:44] Fatal error: /home/phablet/dev_tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.swdev.currencyconverter_0.1_all.click failed to install.
pkcon failed

I tried selecting other frameworks to not avail.  This is probably some basic configuration detail I am missing.  What can it be?

Thanks,
-G